# regex for combining length, inclusion and exclusion?

Tags: python, regex

A search on SO with just `[regex]` gave me 249'446 hits and a search with `[regex] inclusion exclusion` gave me 47 hits but I guess none of the latter (maybe some of the former?) fit my case.

I am also aware, e.g. about this regex page https://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html,
but I guess there might be a regex concept which I am not yet familiar with
and would be grateful for hints.

Here is a minimal example of what I am trying to do with a given list of strings.

Find all items which:

- have a fixed defined number of characters, i.e. length
- must include all characters from a certain list (doesn't matter at what position and if multiple times)
- must NOT include any characters from a certain list

Constructs like:  `[ei^no]{4}`, `((?![no])[ei]){4}` and a lot of other more complex trials didn't give the desired results.

Hence, I currently implemented this as a 3 step process with checking the length, doing a search and a match. This looks pretty cumbersome and inefficient to me.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

**Script:**

```
import re

items = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve']

count          = 4
mustContain    = 'ei'   # all of these charactes at least once
mustNotContain = 'no'   # none of those chars

hits1 = []
for item in items:
    if len(item)==count:
        hits1.append(item)
print("Hits1:",hits1)

hits2 = []
for hit in hits1:
    regex = '[{}]'.format(mustContain)
    if re.search(regex,hit):
        hits2.append(hit)
print("Hits2:", hits2)

hits3 = []
for hit in hits2:
    regex = '[{}]'.format(mustNotContain)
    if re.match(regex,hit):
        hits3.append(hit)
print("Hits3:", hits3)
```

**Result:**

```
Hits1: ['four', 'five', 'nine']
Hits2: ['five', 'nine']
Hits3: ['five']
```

Comment: I think you are looking for a single pattern like `^(?=.{4}$)(?=[^ei\n]*[ei])(?![^no\n]*[no]).+$` https://regex101.com/r/XRW604/1 like `hits = [item for item in items if re.match(r"(?=.{4}$)(?=[^ei\n]*[ei])(?![^no\n]*[no]).+$", item)]`

Comment: Why use a regex for this at all? Something like `[item for item in items if all(rule(item) for rule in [length(4), containsAll("ei"), containsNone("no")])]` is substantially more self-documenting.

Comment: @Thefourthbird thank you, this seems to do the trick. If you post it as answer, I can upvote/accept and close this question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you, haven't thought about this self-documenting Python solution. If you post it as answer, I can upvote. The reason for a regex is that I could use it in other languages as well or in some text editors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in a regex approach, you can create a single dynamic pattern that looks like:

```
^(?=.{4}$)(?![^no\n]*[no])(?=[^e\n]*e)[^i\n]*i.*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=.{4}$)` Assert 4 characters
- `(?![^no\n]*[no])` Assert no occurrence of `n` or `o` to the right using a leading [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- `(?=[^e\n]*e)` Assert an `e` char to the right
- `[^i\n]*i` Match any char except `i` and then match `i`
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `$` end of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hshtyt/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/UY16Cx).

Example

```
import re

items = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'tree']
hits = [item for item in items if re.match(r"(?=.{4}$)(?![^no\n]*[no])(?=[^e\n]*e)[^i\n]*i.*$", item)]

print(hits)
```

Output

```
['five']
```

---

Using a variation of `all` and a list comprehension:

```
items = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'tree']

count = 4
mustContain = ["e", "i"]  # all of these characters at least once
mustNotContain = ["n", "o"]  # none of those chars

hits = [
    item for item in items if
    len(item) == count and
    all([c in item for c in mustContain]) and
    all([c not in item for c in mustNotContain])
]
print(hits)
```

Output

```
['five']
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/09rqsd).

Comment: Great answer! Only, how do you check that all "must contain" chars are present at least once? If I am not wrong, your regex will (wrongly) match "tree"

Comment: @gimix I see, you are right. It would be like this `^(?=.{4}$)(?![^no\n]*[no])(?=[^e\n]*e)[^i\n]*i.*$` See https://regex101.com/r/hshtyt/1 Let me update the answer.

Comment: @Thefourthbird assuming a more general case that the length of the strings is much longer and the including characters as well, e.g. here: `eixy`. Is it then correct that the expression would grow for each character, here to: `'^(?=.{4}$)(?![^no\n]*[no])(?=[^e\n]*e)(?=[^x\n]*x)(?=[^y\n]*y)[^i\n]*i.*$'`? If the number of characters to be included is maybe 10 or 20 (then of course with longer items in the list), it would grow to a pretty lengthy expression. Is there maybe a shorter way for more than 2 characters to be included? Well, the regex could be generated programmatically.

Comment: @theozh If you want to assert all the characters, then you have to assert all of them indeed. I have added another solution, that may be easier to maintain.

Comment: @Thefourthbird thank you for this addition. I was trying to implement jonrsharpe's comment and came up with something similar what you just added. It works. Although, the reason why I asked for a regex was that I could (re-)use it e.g. in Perl or a text editor. And furthermore, to benefit from the simple "case-insensitive"-regex flag which of course can also be implemented with the other solution.

Comment: @theozh You can dynamically generate the regex to keep it maintainable if the pattern becomes very large. If you want to use for example perl, perhaps this page about [Pre-Defined Subroutines](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#define) is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the "trick" which I was missing was the "Positive lookahead" `(?=regex)`.
I guess the regex in @Thefourthbird's solution can be shortened,
unless I overlooked something and somebody will prove me wrong.
The regex for the included characters can be generated dynamically.

The regex for the original minimal example of the question would be:

```
^(?=.{4}$)(?!.*[no])(?=.*e)(?=.*i)
```

**Script:** (dynamically generated regex)

```
import re

items = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 
         'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 
         'tree', 'mean', 'mine', 'fine', 'dime', 'eire']

count          = 4
mustContain    = 'ei'   # all of these characters at least once
mustNotContain = 'no'   # none of those chars

hits = []
regex1 = '^(?=.{' + str(count) + '}$)'                                # limit number of chars
regex2 = '(?!.*[' + mustNotContain + '])' if mustNotContain else ''   # excluded chars
regex3 = ''.join(['(?=.*{})'.format(c) for c in mustContain])         # included chars
regex  = regex1 + regex2 + regex3

for item in items:
    if re.match(regex,item,re.IGNORECASE):
        hits.append(item)
print("Hits:", hits)
```

**Result:**

```
Hits: ['five', 'dime', 'eire']
```